# How to fix: When I scroll down the main menu jumps to the right side of the screen

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am helping design a WordPress website and I am having some issues getting it working correctly.

Just as the title says the menu jumps to the right side of the screen when you scroll down.

Here is a link to the website I am working on:
www.taftpower.com

I'm not even sure what to search for to find answers to similar issues.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to UX.SE @JavaNinja. I think you've posted this question to the wrong forum though. Implementation questions belong in the main Stack Overflow site. Just a quick check of your code. It looks like a z-index issue with your elements. It's not jumping to the right side, it's being hidden behind your body content because you have a js stickied header.  :)

Comment: Agree with nightning. This question belongs on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it can be solved by giving `#menu_wrap` this additional style :

```
#menu_wrap {
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
}
```

Fixed elements behave as if they were static when no positioning is defined so it will place itself in the natural flow of the document, in this case to the right of the main content. Specifying both left and right as 0 and giving it auto margin is just a neat trick to center absolute or fixed position elements.

Comment: Thank you this worked well but I had to remove " display: inline; ".

Comment: Appreciate the update. I see it jumps a bit when the switch is made. Looks like that can be adjusted with topSpacing in the sticky function. Just a sidenote though